# How to delete a Test Class WITHOUT using eclipse

Tags: class, unit-test, delete

I cannot install Eclipse, even if I wanted to.  It is not approved software for my org.

How can test classes be deleted from production, using deployments?
There no 'active' checkbox when I am editing the classes in sandbox mode, so I can't just deactivate the test class, and i cant deploy a deleted class to prod...  how the heck is this done?

I dont want to use ANT or special software.  SF must have a native way to achieve this.  And if not...  then I am very disappointed in humanity.

Comment: lols one easy way is to comment out using /* at the start and */ at the end of the class, there by commenting out  the complete class and deploy it using change sets (standard deploy mechanism provided by salesforce). Wish someone comes up with something better, but for now I am sure this solution should restore your faith in humanity :D

Comment: Heh yeah that's what I ended up doing.  Well actually i deleted all the contents of the test method for now.  I found a knowledge article stating that IDE is the only way to fully delete them.

Comment: @DownstairsB There's multiple ways to achieve your goals. You might want to revisit this question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this with only the software that comes installed with Windows/Linux/Mac. These instructions will be for Windows.

### Create a Folder

Make a folder on your desktop. You'll want this so you can keep your files in order.

### Create package.xml

Open Notepad (Start > Accessories > Notepad). Copy the following text into the text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

Save this file as **package.xml** within the folder you created. *NOTE*: You have to change "Save as type" to "All files (*.*)", or Notepad will "helpfully" add a ".txt" extension that we don't want.

### Create destructiveChanges.xml

Create a new file in Notepad (File > New). Copy the following text into your text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>SomeTestClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

Change **SomeTestClass** to the class you want to delete.

Save this file in the folder you created as **destructiveChanges.xml** (note the capital C in "changes"). Again, make sure that you saved it as "All files (*.*)".

At this point, you have two files in your folder. Open the folder, select both XML files, right-click, and choose "Send To > Compressed Folder". The default name is fine.

You're all set up at this point. Now, you just need to deploy the file.

Go to http://workbench.developerforce.com/, login using your production credentials, then choose "Migration > Deploy", upload your file, and confirm the process.

See this article (not mine: http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2013/12/deploying-destructive-changes-using.html) for some pictures and nice cloud-like palettes.

Comment: Interesting.  I never played with the workbench before.  Thanks!  Maybe I can get away without installing Eclipse :)

Comment: This is brilliant and such a huge time saver! There are so many dependencies with the Force.com IDE (Java/Network settings). I wish I knew about this before! :) Thank you!

Comment: What would `destructiveChanges.xml` look like if it contained multiple classes and multiple triggers?

Comment: @Robs `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>SomeTestClass</members>
        <members>SomeOtherClass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>SomeTrigger</members>
        <members>SomeOtherTrigger</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>`

Comment: Looks like I need a test class to pass in order to delete the class. Does this class need to call the class being deleted?

Comment: @MatthewMetros You need to make sure your test level is set to RunLocalTests in order to run any remaining tests. The class being deleted does not need coverage (nor should it be referenced anywhere, as this will cause a CompileFail error).

Comment: I just tried this but the Apex classes are still there after it ran. My settings were: "Rollback on Error = true", "Test Level: RunLocalTests" and everything else unchecked. After the 5 minutes or so of tests ran I refreshed my Apex classes but the ones I was trying to delete are still there. Any ideas/tips?

Comment: @ChristopherD.Emerson Check your Deployment Status in Setup. It will report any errors and/or what was modified.

Comment: @ChristopherD.Emerson Did you get this figured out?  I'm having the same issue today, and this process has always worked.  I see no errors when I check Deployment Status in Setup.  The deployment ran fine, all tests passed, but the class is still there afterwards.  I've verified the two files are correct, class name is spelled right, etc.  I did notice "Number of Components Deployed" is zero, but I think it's always shown that when deleting, but I'm not sure.  It's always worked in the past so I haven't really paid attention to that.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I tried again and made sure "Single Package" was checked and this time it worked, and I did notice "Number of Components Deployed" was one this time.  So it looks like that option must be checked for this to work.

Comment: @Florissant53 Yes, you need Single Package mode in ordinary cases.

Comment: @Florissant53 I finally got it working. Sadly I don't remember the *exact* thing I was missing but am fairly certain it had to do w/making sure my settings were a certain way in the workbench wizard. The ones that may have been involved (and my settings) were: 
`Run Tests Enabled = true`
`Rollback on Error = true`
`Check Only = false` 

Was nice to get it finally working but it still is a pretty spooky process! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Based on this post on tooling API:

http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/force-com-tooling-api-create-apex-class-apex-trigger-dynamically-and-updatedelete-apex-trigger-apex-class-using-tooling-api-with-rest-api/

I tried deleting a class from my developer account and I was able to do it using  workbench by just providing the class Id and using delete( Sys admin profile)

I am not sure if this would apply for your PRD org. Would be worth giving this a try.

[image]

> Deleting a Apex Class:
>
> // [Status=No Content, StatusCode=204] public void deleteApexClass() {
>       HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/ApexClass/'+oid,'DELETE');
>       String responseJson = getResponse(req); // Store the result to do something }

Comment: Nice idea, rao, but I'm pretty sure the tooling API can't do this, because it's synchronous, and the user has to run all tests in order to change a file in prod. I don't have a production I can test this on, but you're welcome to actually try and do so. I'd love to see it be that easy, because it's far less complicated than my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried it in my developer account on na14 instance and the class was deleted, is there any difference between an actual PRD instance compared to a developer PRD instance?

Comment: Class access is greatly relaxed compared to prod instances. In the workbench, you can also go to "info" > "metadata types & components" > "ApexClass", open "Components", then the class, then hover over "Id" and choose "delete". Same thing as the tooling API without having to remember the URL.

Comment: I do not have access to a PRD org to test this too. I was not sure if this would work in an actual PRD org so I had the disclaimer asking the OP to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to deleting a class using the Force.com Migration Tool which uses Ant.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes

Comment: User "can't" install software, although using the migration tool isn't strictly an install (just unzipping), it's still extra software that IT might not like. Personally, that's what I'd do though. I like the migration tool.

Comment: He said he can't install Eclipse, he didn't mention Ant / other command line tools. Ultimately it comes down to his companys IT policy and how literally he wants to take it.

Comment: "I dont want to use ANT or special software. SF must have a native way to achieve this." -- I think that this kind of suggests that OP can't or won't use Ant.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete classes via the Workbench but as all of you know this currently does not work in production environments as it is mandatory that you run all the tests when deleting a class (which is also why Rao's answer won't help). You can, however, do this via a SOAP call using some SOAP request builder.

You would have to send a [`CompileAndTestRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest_request.htm) and list the classes you want to delete under `deleteClasses`.

As far as I'm aware (but not quite sure) the Workbench also uses SOAP calls so in theory it could be changed to allow this as well.