# Test Class coverage error

Tags: visualforce, failing-tests

I'm trying to deploy a Controller, VF Page, and Test Class into Production, but keep getting an error that my Code Coverage is under 75% in Production - even though the Code Coverage is over 90% in Sandbox.

Did some digging and found an old Test Class created by a previous Admin that is failing in Sandbox.

Here's the code for the Test Class:

```
@isTest 
public class MyCustomVFPage_CTR_Test 
{
static testMethod void testMethod1() 
{
 Account a=new Account(Name='Test',Website='Test');
    insert a;         
Contact contact=new Contact(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John', Account=a, 
Qualification__c='Marketing Qualified');
    insert contact;  


    Test.StartTest(); 

        PageReference pageRef = Page.MyCustomVFPage; // Add your VF page Name here
        pageRef.getParameters().put('ResponseCode', 'Test');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('ObjectId', String.valueOf(contact.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        MyCustomVFPage_CTR obj = new MyCustomVFPage_CTR();

        obj.InitPage(); 

    Test.StopTest();
}
}
```

Here's the code for the VF Page:

```
<apex:page id="Page" showHeader="false" controller="MyCustomVFPage_CTR" action="{!InitPage}" cache="false">
    <apex:form >
        Thank you for your response.
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here's the code for the Controller:

```
<apex:page >
</apex:page>
```

We no longer use this VF page. Can anyone advise on either: 1). How to update the Test Class so that I can deploy my new code or 2). How to delete the old, unused code so that I can deploy the new code?

Comment: Feel free to follow my simple [step-by-step guide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46617/2984) to accomplish your goals. Requires no actual programming skills or extra software than what you should already have on your computer.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think your comment deserves it's position in the answer section.

Comment: @sfdcfox YAYYYYY!!!!! IT WORKED (and just in the nick of time! thank you so so much!!!