# How can I disable my existing Apex REST Webservice in production?

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest, restresource

I have an existing Apex REST Webservice configured in production for consumption by a partner for Lead creation.
However, we are not working with that partner anymore and hence want to disable this Lead creation API for them.

How should I do this? Should I comment out the code of this class(I don't hope so)?

OR should I just delete this Apex class?

Comment: If you are not working with the partner, you should instead ensure that they don't have access to the system anymore. That will itself take care of disabling any API for them.

Comment: Here's a [super-simple example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46617/2984) of how to delete a class from production using only the software found on your OS that I wrote a number of years ago. If deletion is what you're looking for, this is perhaps one of the easiest.

Comment: How was your partner authenticating? Was it being done via an OAuth 2.0 flow (if so, which one?) or is your REST endpoint made public via a site/community?

Comment: if the partner had a unique profile or permission set for that apex class, you could remove access to the class on that profile/permission set

Comment: @JayantDas I am looking for a way to disable the API altogether for everyone.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Deleting the class itself looks like the best option here. Thank you for your example. It's really helpful.

Comment: @DerekF It is exposed via a public page

Comment: @cropredy No that is not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, based on the comments by fellow developers/consultants here, I have come to a conclusion to delete the Webservice class altogether from Salesforce.

Refer to @sfdcfox's comment for the example to delete classes from org